# Gatsby Config Not Changing Color Theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, blogs

I'm new to static site development for blogs and am trying to use Gatsby. I've tried to change the background and theme color of a starter from pink (#ed64a6) to purple (#702da1). However when I put it into the `gatsby-config.js` and run `gatsby develop` nothing changes.

This is `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-personal-website-starter`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#702da1`,
        theme_color: `#702da1`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/assets/images/gatsby-icon.png`
      }
    }
```

And the color from the header is still pink.

[image]

`gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` results in the same issue. This might seem like a silly question but what do I need to do in this case to change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background_color` property from [`gatsby-plugin-manifest`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-manifest/) stands for PWA (**P**rogressive **W**eb **A**pps) features, not for the main `background-color` CSS property.

To change the [styling for any component or element,](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/styling/) just add a CSS/SCSS, JS, modules, etc:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import "./styles.css"   

export default function Home() {
  return <Layout>Hello world!</Layout>
}
```

In your `styles.css`:

```
a {
  color: red:
}

a.active{
  color: blue;
}
```

Keep in mind that [Gatsby's `<Link>`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/) component (because it extends from `@reach/router` from React) adds an additional feature to mark as active the current page (or partial path) with the `activeClassName` `prop`;

```
<Link
  to="/"
  {/* This assumes the `active` class is defined in your CSS */}
  activeClassName="active"
>
```